# TableLayout below Listview not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-tablelayout

I want to show a `TableLayout` below a `Listview` (*where the the no. of items are dynamically added*). I referred to a similar question before, but it didn't work for me. I am using `android:layout_below` to set the `TableLayout` below the `Listview` but it still doesn't work, I would appreciate anyone guiding me on how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
        android:paddingBottom="100dip"
        android:paddingTop="70dip" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Items"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="idvalue_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total Cost"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="idvalue_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you prefer to use the `CoordinatorLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`? `layout_below` does not work for `CoordinatorLayout`, only for `RelativeLayout`, see here for `LayoutParams` info for  [CoordinatorLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html) | [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). Also, would help if you provide a link to the question you are referring to.

Comment: @sept i have changed the coordinatorlayout to relative layout then also layout_below is not working

Comment: I noticed that all of the child views have `match_parent`/`fill_parent` set to their **width** and **height**, I think that the `TableLayout` maybe displayed, but it's not visible since that the `ListView` is taking all the space?

Comment: @sept yes tablelayout is not visible and what should i do to make it visible and to set it below the listview

Comment: It depends on how you want it to look like.. Do you want it to have the height of the `ListView` and the `TableLayout` to be the same?

Comment: ok if i keep the  height of the ListView and the TableLayout to be the same then what should be the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So as per our discussion in the comments section on taking a look at your code, it seems you want to have both the `ListView` and the `TableLayout` to have equal **height** (*because you included `layout_weight` to both of them*).

So in order to produce your desired output, do the following.

1. Use a `RelativeLayout` as the Parent Layout.
2. Add a `LinearLayout` with `weightSum` = 2 and `orientation=vertical`, and put the `ListView` and the `TableLayout` inside it, where both of their height = 0dp and the `layout_weight` = 1.

Here's a sample snippet for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Doing so would result to something like this:

[image]

PS: This is just the display when checking the layout in the Android Studio preview, not when the code is running.

Comment: Are you new with layouts? I added a code snippet for your reference. Good luck and happy coding. :)